# ChartAngular and REST data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I'm trying out the ChartAngular built by Bilal Budhani.

I got it going to display some data from a JSON data set, but now I'm trying to plug in by accessing some data through a REST API which is failing.

The data looks like this:

```
 [{
      "TypeCount": 10,
      "SentDate": "2014-08-29T00:00:00.000Z"
    }, {
      "TypeCount": 5,
      "SentDate": "2014-08-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    }, {
      "TypeCount": 8,
      "SentDate": "2014-08-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    }, {
      "TypeCount": 24,
      "SentDate": "2014-08-26T00:00:00.000Z"
    }]
```

My HTML is simple looks like this:

```
   <html>
    <body ng-app="MyChartApp">
      <div ng-controller="BarChartCtrl">
          <barchart id="bar-example" data-options="chart_options"></barchart>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

And finally my controller code is below:

```
  (function() {
      angular.module('MyChartApp', ['ChartAngular']).
      controller('BarChartCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
          $http.get("http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json")
              .success(function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
              });
          $scope.chart_options = {
              data: response,
              xkey: 'SentDate',
              ykeys: ['TypeCount'],
              labels: ['Message Count']
          };
      })
    }());
```

When I run this it says my chart is undefined.

I thought it would work because I'm using the .success method....

UPDATE:

Ok I changed my code and it works outside the promise but not inside. This code works:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('MyChartApp', ['ChartAngular']);
    var BarChartCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json")
            .then(function (response)
            {
                console.log(response.data);
                var sample_data = response.data;    
            });

          var chart_data = [{ SentDate: '2014-08-29T00:00:00.000Z', TypeCount: 100 },
                        { SentDate: '2014-08-28T00:00:00.000Z', TypeCount: 75 },
                        { SentDate: '2014-08-27T00:00:00.000Z', TypeCount: 50 },
                        { SentDate: '2014-08-26T00:00:00.000Z', TypeCount: 75 }];

            $scope.chart_options = {
                data: chart_data,
                xkey: 'SentDate',
                ykeys: ['TypeCount'],
                labels: ['HL7 Message Count']
            };
    };
    app.controller("BarChartCtrl", BarChartCtrl);    
}());
```

This doesn't:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('MyChartApp', ['ChartAngular']);

    var BarChartCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json")
            .then(function (response)
            {  
          var chart_data = [{ SentDate: '2014-08-29T00:00:00.000Z', TypeCount: 100 },
            { SentDate: '2014-08-28T00:00:00.000Z', TypeCount: 75 },
            { SentDate: '2014-08-27T00:00:00.000Z', TypeCount: 50 },
            { SentDate: '2014-08-26T00:00:00.000Z', TypeCount: 75 }];

                $scope.chart_options = {
                    data: chart_data,
                    xkey: 'SentDate',
                    ykeys: ['TypeCount'],
                    labels: ['HL7 Message Count']
                }; 
            });                    
    };
    app.controller("BarChartCtrl", BarChartCtrl);   
}());
```

Comment: It would appear you are instantiating the `chart_options` variable on the controller before the data is available. Try instantiating it within the success call once the data is available from the `$http` call. This is assuming the data is in the correct format for ChartAngular and is actually returned from the `$http` call.

Comment: I tried that same result. I even tried putting dummy data in and its not working:

Comment: $http.get("http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json")
      .success(function (response) {

          console.log(response);

      $scope.chart_options = {
          data: [
            { SentDate: '2006', TypeCount: 100 },
            { SentDate: '2012', TypeCount: 100 }
          ],
          xkey: 'SentDate',
          ykeys: ['TypeCount'],
          labels: ['HL7 Message Count']
      };


      });

Comment: I would try to recreate the example in the Github repository for ChartAngular and then build out from there...